# Angular best practise to filter component data. Pipe or service?

Tags: angular

Given:
Component

```js
@Component({
  template: `
    <div class="filter">
      <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="fruits">
      <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="vegetables">
      <input type="text"     [(ngModel)]="name">
    </div>

    <div class="items" 
         *ngFor="let item of items$ | async | filterBy:fruits:vegetables:name; trackBy: trackItemById">
      {{item.name}}
      {{item.type}}
    </div>

  `
})
export class ItemsComponent {
  @Select(ItemsState.items)
  public readonly items$: Observable<Item[]>;

  public fruites: boolean;
  public vegetables: boolean;
  public name: string;
}
```

Pipe

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterBy',
  pure: true
})
export class FilterByPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: Item[] = [], fruits: boolean, vegetables: boolean, name: string) {
    return items.filter(/* some filter logic */);
  }
}
```

When:

User select fruits -> show only fruits items on UI (pipe will filter it)

User clicks vegetables -> show only vegetables items on UI (pipe will filter it)

User select both (or by default unselected both) -> show all items

User type name -> show matched items

The question is:

As you can see data filter each time user clicks on checkbox or type input. For example there can be 1000 elements in array. Someone says that filter pipe is bad approach because of it could be slow, they recommend use services for it. But i don't see difference between this approaches. But prefer pipe because it is compact and reusable in UI.

So is there any best practise to filter data in UI, which better and why? Is filter pipe bad approach?

Comment: I think that as best practice you should use pipe only to mutate strings, you don't need the template to do heavy lifting like filtering. Services are made to work with the data itself. also it is a good practice to go with the flow - in this case Angular's.

Comment: @noririco any code examples ?

Comment: your question is about what is better, not for code example. but I can suggest that you check "how to filter data using YOUR STORE SYSTEM"